# Javascript escaping backslash in variable

Tags: javascript

I'm calling some `JSON` and within the `JSON data` one of the fields looks like : `full/content` so I call my data which I have as a variable named `mainData` so i'm trying to grab this field in my `JSON` :

`mainData.full/content` but the slash used within the data field spits out an error. How can I add a trailing slash (escape the slash so I can use it) to be able to grab the data in this field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access it like this: `mainData['full/content']`.